# Objects not displaying separate information. Java OOP

Tags: java, oop

I'm just doing OOP with Java right now, and I've hit a bit of a bump. I have 2 problems, the biggest being the objects not displaying properly. In my employee.java class, I have the following code for displaying the employees/workers.

```
public String getInfo() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName + "\n" + address + "\n" + city + 
                                            "\n" + wageRate + "\n" + hoursWorked;
    }
```

Now, in `employeeTest.java` where I'm doing most of my processing and updating, I have the following created for separate objects:

```
//instantiate 4 employee objects
        employees worker1 = new employees();
        employees worker2 = new employees();
        employees worker3 = new employees();
        employees worker4 = new employees();
```

After that, I attempt to update the employees and display them right after using the following code (it is incomplete for testing reasons).

```
    //declare variables to update employees
    String newFirstName1, newFirstName2, newFirstName3, newFirstName4;
    String newLastName1, newLastName2, newLastName3, newLastName4;
    String newAddress1, newAddress2, newAddress3, newAddress4;
    String newCity1, newCity2, newCity3, newCity4;
    int newHoursWorked1, newHoursWorked2, newHoursWorked3, newHoursWorked4;
    int newWageRate1, newWageRate2, newWageRate3, newWageRate4;

    //update the employee (in progress)
    System.out.println("Please enter Employee 1's first name:");
    newFirstName1 = conIn.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter Employee 1's last name:");
    newLastName1 = conIn.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter Employee 1's address:");
    newAddress1 = conIn.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter Employee 1's city:");
    newCity1 = conIn.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter Employee 1's hours worked:");
    newHoursWorked1 = conIn.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter Employee 1's wage rate:");
    newWageRate1 = conIn.nextInt();
    worker1.setFirstName(newFirstName1);
    worker1.setLastName(newLastName1);

    //Display the employees
    System.out.println("Employee 1");
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    System.out.println(worker1.getInfo());
    System.out.println("Employee 2");
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    System.out.println(worker2.getInfo());
    System.out.println("Employee 3");
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    System.out.println(worker3.getInfo());
    System.out.println("Employee 4");
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    System.out.println(worker4.getInfo());
```

However, this updates ALL workers. Ex. I enter "John" for the first name, `worker1-4` are all updated with the first name "John". I only want `worker1` to be updated so I know it works.

Second problem is that the following code is skipped while executing and testing the code.

```
    //change the company name
    String newCompanyName;
    System.out.println("Please enter a new company name:");
    newCompanyName = conIn.nextLine();
    employees.setCompanyName(newCompanyName);
```

### Edit 3

Code of `employeeTest.java` below

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package employeerionmurphy;
import employeerionmurphy.employees.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Owner
 */
public class employeeTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        //declare scanner
        Scanner conIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        //instantiate 4 employee objects
        employees worker1 = new employees();
        employees worker2 = new employees();
        employees worker3 = new employees();
        employees worker4 = new employees();

        //Display the employees
        System.out.println("Employee 1");
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(worker1.getInfo());
        System.out.println("Employee 2");
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(worker2.getInfo());
        System.out.println("Employee 3");
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(worker3.getInfo());
        System.out.println("Employee 4");
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(worker4.getInfo());

        //spacer for user readability
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");

        //declare variables to update employees
        String newFirstName1, newFirstName2, newFirstName3, newFirstName4;
        String newLastName1, newLastName2, newLastName3, newLastName4;
        String newAddress1, newAddress2, newAddress3, newAddress4;
        String newCity1, newCity2, newCity3, newCity4;
        int newHoursWorked1, newHoursWorked2, newHoursWorked3, newHoursWorked4;
        int newWageRate1, newWageRate2, newWageRate3, newWageRate4;

        //update the employee (in progress)
        System.out.println("Please enter Employee 1's first name:");
        newFirstName1 = conIn.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter Employee 1's last name:");
        newLastName1 = conIn.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter Employee 1's address:");
        newAddress1 = conIn.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter Employee 1's city:");
        newCity1 = conIn.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter Employee 1's hours worked:");
        newHoursWorked1 = conIn.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter Employee 1's wage rate:");
        newWageRate1 = conIn.nextInt();
        worker1.setFirstName(newFirstName1);
        worker1.setLastName(newLastName1);

        //spacer for user readability
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");

        //upgrade the wage rate of the employee that has a wage rate of zero
        //(in progress)


        //spacer for user readability
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");

        //display employees
        System.out.println("Employee 1");
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(worker1.getInfo());
        System.out.println("Employee 2");
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(worker2.getInfo());
        System.out.println("Employee 3");
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(worker3.getInfo());
        System.out.println("Employee 4");
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(worker4.getInfo());

        //spacer for user readability
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");

        //display the employees name and gross pay
        System.out.println(employees.getTotalPay());

        //spacer for user readability
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");

        //change the company name
        String newCompanyName;
        System.out.println("Please enter a new company name:");
        newCompanyName = conIn.nextLine();
        employees.setCompanyName(newCompanyName);

        //spacer for user readability
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");

        //display the employees
        System.out.println("Employee 1");
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(worker1.getInfo());
        System.out.println("Employee 2");
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(worker2.getInfo());
        System.out.println("Employee 3");
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(worker3.getInfo());
        System.out.println("Employee 4");
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(worker4.getInfo());

        //spacer for user readability
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Built by Rion Murphy");

    }
}
```

Code of `employee.java` below

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package employeerionmurphy;

import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Owner
 */
public class employees {
    //declare variables
    static String firstName;
    static String lastName;
    static String address;
    static String city;
    static int hoursWorked;
    static int wageRate;
    final double OVERTIME = 40.00;

    public static String companyName = "Grand Company";

    //declare a constructor to initalize all fields to null
    public employees() {
    }

    //declare a constructor to hold the actual values in the variables.
    public employees(String newFirstName, String newLastName, 
            String newAddress, String newCity, int newHoursWorked, int newWageRate) {
        firstName = newFirstName;
        lastName = newLastName;
        address = newAddress;
        city = newCity;
        hoursWorked = newHoursWorked;
        wageRate = newWageRate;

    }

    //accessors for the variables
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public int getHoursWorked() {
        return hoursWorked;
    }
    public int getWageRate() {
        return wageRate;
    }

    //mutators for hoursWorked and wageRate
    public void setHoursWorked(int newHoursWorked) {
        hoursWorked = newHoursWorked;
    }
    public void setWageRate(int newWageRate) {
        wageRate = newWageRate;
    }

    //mutators for the string variables
    public void setFirstName(String newFirstName) {
        firstName = newFirstName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String newLastName) {
        lastName = newLastName;
    }
    public void setAddress(String newAddress) {
        address = newAddress;
    }
    public void setCity(String newCity) {
        city = newCity;
    }

    //company name mutator
    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }
    public static void setCompanyName(String newCompanyName) {
        companyName = newCompanyName;
    }

    //printing out employee information
    public String getInfo() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName + "\n" + address + "\n" + city + "\n" + wageRate + "\n" + hoursWorked;
    }

    //printing out employee name and totalPay
    public static String getTotalPay() {
        //calculate total pay
        double totalPay;
        int overtimeHours;
        if (hoursWorked > 40) {
            overtimeHours = hoursWorked - 40;
            totalPay = (overtimeHours * (wageRate * 1.5)) + (40 * wageRate);
        } else {
            totalPay = hoursWorked * wageRate;
        }
        //return the name and the total pay of employee
        return firstName + " " + lastName + "\n" + totalPay;
    }

    //console operations done below
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        //Prompt user for all data (use previous mutators to set hoursWorked and wageRate
        Scanner conIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your first name: ");
        firstName = conIn.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter your last name: ");
        lastName = conIn.next();


//        Errors detected in the below line of code, will repair at a later date
//        
        System.out.println("Please enter your address: ");
        address = conIn.nextLine();       
        System.out.println("Please enter your city: ");
        city = conIn.nextLine();


        System.out.println("Please enter your hours worked: ");
        hoursWorked = conIn.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter your wage rate: ");
        wageRate = conIn.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");

        //spacer for user readability
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");

        //print the fields to the console (except the constant)
        System.out.println("First Name: " + firstName);
        System.out.println("Last Name: " + lastName);
        System.out.println("Address: " + address);
        System.out.println("City: " + city);
        System.out.println("Hours Worked: " + hoursWorked);
        System.out.println("Wage Rate: " + wageRate);
        System.out.println("Company Name: " + companyName);

        //spacer for user readability
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");

        //calculate and return gross pay (time and a half over 40 hours)
        double totalPay;
        int overtimeHours;
        if (hoursWorked > 40) {
            overtimeHours = hoursWorked - 40;
            totalPay = (overtimeHours * (wageRate * 1.5)) + (40 * wageRate);
        } else {
            totalPay = hoursWorked * wageRate;
        }
        System.out.println("The total pay for " + hoursWorked + " hours is " + totalPay);

        //spacer for user readability
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what your setter methods look like and your field declarations in the `employees` class.

Comment: We see no code in your question where you are actually change an Employee object's state except for worker1's setXXXName. So if you *are* in fact changing the Employee's state then perhaps your Employee fields have been declared static or you're having all Employee variables refer to the same object.

Comment: for a question that's tagged `oop` There sure seems to be a lack of classes.

Comment: Where is the "skipped" block in your code?  How do you know that it's indeed skipped?  Have you run your code under debugger?

Comment: you should reuse variables in your code.

Comment: and you're not showing us the context of that skipped code.  For All we know, it can be in side a `if(false){...}` block

Comment: You're still not showing your Employee fields, the city, state, and name fields.

Comment: The skipped code context is exactly that, there is no if statement, it is just inside the main class (employeeTest.java) If you want me to put the entire employeeTest.java main class in, please let me know.

Comment: Can you post your entire employeeTest.java class? Posting it like this makes it confusing. Perhaps an error is thrown before getting to the snippet of code you provided?

Also you should brush up on naming conventions for classes (capitalize!)

Comment: No, we want the `employees` class.

Comment: I'll post both for you guys.

Comment: I know, but for his second problem, I'm confused as to where he's executing those lines of code.

Comment: Remove the `static` in front of your field declarations. those should be instance fields.

Comment: pleease read and use the java code conventions: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yup, they're static

```
static String firstName;
static String lastName;
static String address;
static String city;
static int hoursWorked;
static int wageRate;
```

Get rid of the `static` modifier.  `static` that there's only one of that variable, not one per instance.

When you change a static variable like `firstName` you're changing the `firstName` for the class itself.  All instances will use the same `firstName`.

Comment: Okay, that fixed most problems, except it gave me a compile error with getTotalPay. (I had to make getTotalPay non-static to make it compatiable with the new types of variables.)

Comment: @RionMurphMurphy `static` applies to methods too.  your `getTotalPay` method is not related to a specific instance, and can't use instance variables(non-static), because there is no instance

Comment: Answer me one last question, everything is now working, so thank you for bringing my attention to the static (didn't fully understand it, it seems) But what about the one problem where my code won't pause to let me enter my companyName?

Comment: @RionMurphMurphy  I can't see any reason why that code should be skipped.  does `"Please enter a new company name:"` get printed?  does the code after it get printed?

Comment: Yes to both, but for some reason it doesn't stop after the `"Please enter a new company name:"` but it continues to print the rest to the console.

Comment: @RionMurphMurphy well that's certainly different from `"these lines are skipped"`.  It would probably be best to make a new question; one for each question